# Laravel 5.1 - Relationships through two parallel pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-5.1, relationships

Assume we have four tables; Matrix, Row, Column and Cell.

```
Matrix
  id

Row
  id
  matrix_id
  label

Column
  id
  matrix_id
  label

Cell
  id
  row_id
  column_id
  text
```

The relationships thus look something like

```
    Matrix
   /      \
  Row   Column
   \      /
     Cell
```

Can the relationship between Matrix and Cell through Row and Column be represented somehow in Laravel 5.1? So that I could for example have a `cells()` method on Matrix that returns a Relation to the cells it has through Row and Column.

Comment: you can chain them like Matrix::with('row','row.cell') than you get the cell through row

Comment: or hasManyThrough http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through